# Showing the intro or full image in the Article Manager

Tags: administration, article-manager

Hopefully someone will find this an interesting question...

Is there any way that I can show a small thumbnail (doesn't need to be a generated thumbnail, just a scaled down version of the original image) of either the full article image or intro image in a new column in the Article Manager list of articles, maybe between the 'Status' and 'Title' column?

Is it possible to override the layout of that admin page?

If it is possible, how could I add the image?

Many thanks for any help given...

Leila

Answer (score 1):

[Template Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) work also for Administration. Just copy content of `/administrator/components/com_content/views/articles/tmpl` to `/administrator/templates/isis/html/com_content/articles/`. Then you can edit items view (`/templates/isis/html/com_content/articles/default.php`) and add the images. Of course if you use administration template other then ISIS just change it in above urls.